# uninitialized constant Arel::Visitors::VISITORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase DB with SqlAnywhere from my rails app (the sybase is a secondary db), but when I declare my connection, I receive the follow exception

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Arel::Visitors::VISITORS):
```

I'm connecting like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter:  "sqlanywhere",
    username: "xxxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxxx",
    host: ip_address
  )
```

Comment: The `activerecord-sqlanywhere-adapter` was last updated for Rails 3 and has not been touched in 11 years. Since it leverages Arel internals (as all adapters do), those internals have been updated significantly since then and this gem is no longer compatible.

Comment: @engineersmnky does that mean that there's no way or support to connect from rails to a sybase/sqlanywhere database? I think I'm going to commit suicide...

Comment: Maybe you could try [`tinytds`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) and the [`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter)

Comment: Hi @ClaudioScabbiaSepúlveda... did you fin a solution of this?. Please!